# How to turn off ASLR in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux

I want to turn off ASLR on my own PC. But each time I type "sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space", the system shows that　"Permission denied". How can I make it work? By the way, my OS kernel is 2.6.30.

Hope anyone can give me a hand.

Regards.

Comment: This is a valid question on shell programming.

Comment: Why do you want to turn off ASLR?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common problem with sudo and shell redirection. The "sudoness" doesn't propagate past the redirection. One way to get around it is

```
sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /path/to/file"
```

Answer (score 11):

In your command, the I/O redirection `>` is handled by the current shell. The command is seen by the interpreter as 3 parts:

1. `sudo echo 0`
2. `>`
3. `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`

The `echo` is executed using the superuser privilege while the current shell (with normal user privilege) tries to write to `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`, and thus triggers a `Permission denied` error.

There are several ways to overcome this. The first way is to run a shell with superuser privilege and pass the command to the shell using the `-c` switch:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space"
```

(You may use `sh` for POSIX shell and `bash` for Bash)

Another way is to use the `tee` command. The `tee` command copies the contents from standard input to the standard output (usually means the "screen") as well as the listed files. Therefore, the following command prints the character `A` to the standard output as well as the files `output1.txt` and `output2.txt`.

```
echo A | tee output1.txt output2.txt
```

In your problem, writing to `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` needs the superuser privilege while `echo`-ing `0` does not. So, the solution is:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space >/dev/null
```

The final redirection to `/dev/null` prevents the `0` from printing to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

The `sudo` only works for your echo command (not after the pipe).

You can try:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```